# Blender 2.82a bug? Some faces always shading flat even though all faces were set to shade smooth?

Tags: shaders

[image: flat shading]

**This started happening randomly**. I was in edit mode tinkering with the mesh and merging a few vertices. When I came out of edit mode I noticed the shading was messed up. No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the faces to shade smooth again.

Has anyone run into this problem? Here is the file:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use blend-exchange if you want to provide files for us to check. Random file sharing services won't keep them up long enough. Also, read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please), if you want to know more.

Comment: Done....................

Comment: Turn off autosmooth.

Comment: @Leander Yes! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this happen and it was double verts.

Removed them by selecting all verts and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> *Merge > By Distance*

Comment: It says "Removed 0 vertices". Looks like it wasn't the problem.

Comment: What about normals? Recalculate in Edit Mode, select all faces and then Ctrl+Shift+N.

Comment: I've considered normals, too. Recalculating or flipping doesn't help. I attached the file, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: The polygons (quads) in your mesh are bent diagonally.**

[image: distorted polygon]

Bent or distorted quads will produce shading issues, because Blender (or any other 3D software, including Game Engines) does not know, in which direction the light has to bounce off. These issues cannot be resolved in any other way than

- either triangulating your mesh
- or straighten the bent polygons

Comment: Triangulating doesn't fix the shading, it's still flat. Also it doesn't explain why this started happening all of the sudden. I wasn't even touching this part of the mesh when the shading broke like this.

Comment: I want to emphasize the fact that all faces were smooth at first. This mesh was built using a cloth simulation, and everything looked fine. Then I was in edit mode in and out for quite some time and at one point the shading broke like this.

Comment: I redid the cloth simulation and it produced a bunch of bent quads, but the smooth shading looks fine. This isn't the issue.